# How to Correctly Add Values to a 3D Array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I am trying to create a three dimensional array that outputs as:

```
[1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2,3]
[1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2,3]
[1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2,3]
[1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2,3]
[1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2,3]
```

Here is the code I have come up with:

```
public class Triples {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[][][] triplet = new int[5][4][3];

        for (int i = 0; i < triplet.length; i++) 
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < triplet[i].length; j++) 
            {
                System.out.print("[");
                for (int k = 0; k < triplet[i][j].length; k++) 
                {
                    triplet[i][j][k] = i+1;
                    System.out.print(triplet[i][j][k] + "," + "");
                }
                System.out.print("]");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

The result I have looks like:

```
[1,1,1,][1,1,1,][1,1,1,][1,1,1,]
[2,2,2,][2,2,2,][2,2,2,][2,2,2,]
[3,3,3,][3,3,3,][3,3,3,][3,3,3,]
[4,4,4,][4,4,4,][4,4,4,][4,4,4,]
[5,5,5,][5,5,5,][5,5,5,][5,5,5,]
```

My issue is I am not sure how to increment the values in the third for loop to go as 1, 2, and 3. I have tried different combinations, but they have resulted with either the same or incorrect result. Any tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply assign the value of `k+1`. That's all

**Explanation:(I am not very good at this.)**
Values of `i` and `j` are not going to change in the `k` loop. So you don't need them. But the value ok `k` does change in every iteration. Also it will reset to `0` every time. But we don't want `0` so change it to `k+1`.
Do put some debug `println` in your statement. They help a lot.

`triplet[i][j][k] = k+1;`

With this the new inner most for loop looks like:

```
for (int k = 0; k < triplet[i][j].length; k++) 
{
    triplet[i][j][k] = k+1;

    //Don't put the comma after last digit.
    if(k==triplet[i][j].length-1) {
        System.out.print(triplet[i][j][k] );
    }else {
        System.out.print(triplet[i][j][k] + "," + "");
    }

}
```

Comment: Wow. That seemed a little too easy. Thank you! Can you maybe explain the reason behind this? I just want to make sure I understand.

Comment: That made sense, no worries. Thank you very much.

Comment: As I said put some `println` statements in every loop. Use Eclipse IDE if you are not using it. It has a very good feature called `Debugging`, google that.

Comment: Yeah eclipse works very well, still learning the debugging feature. Also, just got the privilege to up vote!

Comment: Welcome to Beautiful world of Java and Stackoverflow. All the best!

Answer (score 0):

You need to initial the value of adder in the second loop and then add the value by  1 inside the deeper loop. 
Try this:

```
public class Triples {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[][][] triplet = new int[5][4][3];

        for (int i = 0; i < triplet.length; i++) 
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < triplet[i].length; j++) 
            {
                System.out.print("[");
                for (int k = 0; k < triplet[i][j].length; k++) 
                {
                    triplet[i][j][k] = k+1;
                    System.out.print(triplet[i][j][k] + "," + "");
                }
                System.out.print("]");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does a++ refer to?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Triples {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[][][] triplet = new int[5][4][3];

        for (int i = 0; i < triplet.length; i++) 
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < triplet[i].length; j++) 
            {
                System.out.print("[");
                for (int k = 0; k < triplet[i][j].length; k++) 
                {
                    triplet[i][j][k] = k+1;
                        if(k==triplet[i][j].length-1) 
                            System.out.print(triplet[i][j][k] );
                        else
                            System.out.print(triplet[i][j][k] + ",");
                }
                if(j==triplet[i].length-1) 
                    System.out.print("]");
                else
                    System.out.print("], ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```